# Convert <UL> to <SELECT> and indent children

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, select, html-lists

I've got a wordpress theme which uses jQuery to convert the <nav> into a <select> for usage on small screens. The script creates a <select> on the fly and appends it right to the <nav> element. I then use CSS to hide the <select> on everything above 450px or so....This is all working great.

I need some help modifying the jQuery so that nested <ul>'s (children items) show up as being indented within the <select> element.

---

**Here is the HTML**
(the <select> got added in there on the fly with the jQuery below)

```
<ul id="menu-main-nav" style="">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="has-children has_submenu">
        <a href="#">Pages</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
            <li><a href="#">Homepage Layer Slider</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Homepage &ndash; Lightbox Hero</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Homepage Sidebar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-children has_submenu">
        <a href="#">Features</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
            <li><a href="#">Admin Options Panel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">18 Page Templates</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Theme Designer</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
</ul>

<select>
    <option selected="selected" value="">Select a page:</option>
    <option value="#">Home</option>
    <option value="#">Pages</option>
    <option value="#">Homepage Layer Slider</option>
    <option value="#">Homepage &ndash; Lightbox Hero</option>
    <option value="#">Homepage Sidebar</option>
    <option value="#">Features</option>
    <option value="#">Admin Options Panel</option>
    <option value="#">18 Page Templates</option>
    <option value="#">Theme Designer</option>
    <option value="#">Per-Page Styling</option>
    <option value="#">Blog</option>
    <option value="#">Shop</option>
</select>
```

---

**I'd like for the <select> output to be something like this:**

```
    <select>
    <option selected="selected" value="">Select a page:</option>
    <option value="#">Home</option>
    <option value="#">Pages</option>
    <option value="#">--Homepage Layer Slider</option>
    <option value="#">--Homepage &ndash; Lightbox Hero</option>
    <option value="#">--Homepage Sidebar</option>
    <option value="#">Features</option>
    <option value="#">--Admin Options Panel</option>
    <option value="#">--18 Page Templates</option>
    <option value="#">--Theme Designer</option>
    <option value="#">-Per-Page Styling</option>
    <option value="#">Blog</option>
    <option value="#">Shop</option>
</select>
```

---

**Here's the jQuery:**

```
jQuery("<select />").appendTo("header nav");

// Create default option "Go to..."
jQuery("<option />", {
   "selected": "selected",
   "value"   : "",
   "text"    : "Select a page:"
}).appendTo("nav select");

// Populate dropdown with menu items
jQuery("nav a").each(function() {
 var el = jQuery(this);
 jQuery("<option />", {
     "value"   : el.attr("href"),
     "text"    : el.text()
 }).appendTo("nav select");
});

jQuery("nav select").change(function() {
  window.location = jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val();
});

//Find current menu item from desktop menu
var current_menu_item = jQuery('nav').find('.current-menu-item').text();

//Loop through mobile menu option text and add attribute selected if it matches the above current menu item found.
jQuery("nav select option").each(function(){
  if (jQuery(this).text() == current_menu_item)
    jQuery(this).attr("selected","selected");
});
```

---

I'm super grateful for any guidance you can provide. Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

add to your jquery

```
$( "select" ).addClass( "myClass" );
$('.myClass option').prepend("&nbps;&nbps;&nbps;&nbps;");
```

Comment: Thanks! Definitely on the right track however this code "indents" all select options and I only need to indent the "child pages".

For example, in my HTML example up above, the list-item "Pages" has 3 "children" Homepage Layer Slider, Homepage Lightbox Hero, Homepage Sidebar.....those 3 children need the indent